# Debug error in HTTPHandler : Server side-error occured on sending debug HTTP request

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, httphandler, asp.net-1.1

**Tool:** Visual Studio 2003 Enterprise Architect , ASP.net WebForms 
**Language:** C#

Hello Guys,

I have just implemented HttpHandler for the first time ,I thought I was going ok ,but I'm facing this error

### Error Message:

> Error while trying to run poject: Unable to start debugging on the web server. Server side-error occurred on sending debug HTTP request.
>   Make sure the erver is operating correctly.Verify there are no syntax errors in web.config by doing a Debug.start Without Debugging. You may also want to refer to the ASP.NET and ATL Server debugging topic in the online documentation.

**CODE:**
I have `ImageHandler.cs` class

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
 public ImageHandler()
 {
 }
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
 { 
       //blah blah code
       bytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
     }
    }
```

I have registered WebHandler on the page where I would call for request,

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="ace.ImageHandler" %>
```

I'm calling HttpHandler from gridView

```
    <asp:TemplateColumn>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <img src="ImageHandler.ashx?autoid=<%# Eval("Blob_Id").ToString() %>" width="150" height="100" />
     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Registered the handler in Web.Config

```
 <httphandlers>
  <add verb="GET" path="ace\ImageHandler.ashx" type="ace.ImageHandler, ImageHandler" />
 <httphandlers>
```

## Update:

I used Debug > Start without Debugging and WebApp executed and got this error.

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section 'httphandlers'
>
> **Source Error:**

```
Line 9:   <system.web>
Line 10:    
Line 11:  <httphandlers>
Line 12:   <add verb="*" path="*.ashx" type="ace.ImageHandler, ImageHandler" />
Line 13:   <httphandlers>
```

*Note:* ace is the namespace and `ImageHandler.cs` is a class

**P.S:** I have followed this **[article](http://www.arnebrachhold.de/2005/05/25/custom-http-handlers-in-aspnet/)**

Comment: Select the Start without Debugging error in VS, and it should tell you what the error is.

Comment: @BrianMains I just did that and fixed `</httphandlers>` it didn't had forward slash in it ,I have updated my question and the Error Message persists.

Comment: Can you post some more context surrounding the httphandlers section in the web.config. Also, what version of IIS are you using / targeting?

Comment: @BrianDishaw I'm using the default IIS of Windows XP ,I thnik its iis 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `<httpHandlers>` with the second H as a capital letter.  I just tried it on my project, and the capitalization matters.

Comment: Well It did solved the problem but now I'm getting error, `File or assembly name ImageHandler, or one of its dependencies, was not found.`

Comment: @dotNetSoldier so is ImageHandler.dll in the bin folder?

Comment: I never made .dll I just made a class :/ ,I think I gotta make a .dll ?

Comment: It's looking for an assembly named ImageHandler, and it can't find it.  Rename the type to: `ace.ImageHandler, (assembly name that has ImageHandler in it)`